# React Hooks useState showing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactScrollDetector from 'react-scroll-detector';

const DatePicker = ({ count }) => {
  const [countNew, setCount] = useState(count);
  const handleScrollBottom = () => {
    useEffect(() => setCount((countNew = countNew + 12)));
  };

  const handleScrollTop = () => {
    useEffect(() => setCount((countNew = countNew + 12)));
  };

  return (
    <ReactScrollDetector
      debounceTime={500}
      accuracy={90}
      onScrollBottom={handleScrollBottom}
      onScrollTop={handleScrollTop}
    >
      <div style={{ minHeight: '300px', maxHeight: '300px', overflow: 'auto' }}> </div>
    </ReactScrollDetector>
  );
};
```

> react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook
> call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function
> component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: You placed `useEffect` hooks in the callbacks, they can be only in the functional component body. From the looks of it, I think they are completely superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactScrollDetector from "react-scroll-detector";

    const DatePicker = ({count}) => {
      const [countNew, setCount] = useState(count)
      const handleScrollBottom = () => {
          setCount(countNew + 12)
       }
      const handleScrollTop = ()  => {
        setCount(countNew + 12)
     }
      return (
        <ReactScrollDetector
          debounceTime={500}
          accuracy={90}
          onScrollBottom={handleScrollBottom}
          onScrollTop={handleScrollTop}>
          <div style={{ minHeight: "300px", maxHeight: "300px", overflow: "auto" }}> <div>

        </ReactScrollDetector>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

let your functions like this

```js
const handleScrollBottom = () => setCount(countNew = countNew + 12))
       
const handleScrollTop = ()  => setCount(countNew = countNew + 12))
```

the error

```js
react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation:
```

is because useEffect Hook needs to be outside of the functions for example

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
      
  }, []);
  const bar = () => {};
  const foo = () => {};
  return <div></div>;
}
```